# Displaying the "agreement" field of a DAML contract

Tags: daml

How can I display the contents of the "agreement" field of a DAML contract in Navigator?

For instance this parameterized text from the test_project contract:

```
agreement
  toText landlord <> " promises to let "
  toText tenant <> " live at " <> address
  " until " <> toText expirationDate
```

Comment: As of the latest released SDK, the Navigator cannot display the agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not implemented in Navigator.

---

Some technical background:

The [Ledger API](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/index.html) does include everything needed to compute the agreement text:

- The agreement text expression is included in the [DAML-LF package](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/index.html#daml-lf) returned by the [package service](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/app-arch/index.html#package-service).
- The contract argument (the value of variables used in the agreement expression) is given by the [transaction service](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/app-arch/index.html#transaction-service)

However, Navigator currently does not support DAML-LF expressions.